# XSLT2.0 name space support

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to convert the following xml using xslt.
**Note: I am using name spave in input xml**

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Roottag xmlns="aaa">
    <Employee>
        <name>Nimal</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>Kamal</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>Sunil</name>
    </Employee>
</Roottag>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="//name">
        <xsl:element name="person">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<person>Nimal</person>
<person>Kamal</person>
<person>Sunil</person>
```

**Current output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
        Nimal   
        Kamal   
        Sunil
```

Can any one please help me to solve this name space issue in xslt2.0 transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 and an XSLT 2.0 processor you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="aaa">

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <person>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With an XSLT 1.0 processor you need

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:df="aaa" exclude-result-prefixes="aaa">

    <xsl:template match="df:name">
        <person>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```